# JavaFX - Display list of pictures

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

i would like to display a list of picture in my view, and the list should refresh if i add new photo.  I looked at the ListView which is bindable but i'm wondering if it is the component that i need to display pictures ans i don't want the scroll, i will instead have some link to next page and previous page.  I'm looking for some advice from some people that have done this kind of work, on which component from JavaFx would be suitable for my job.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may create your own control by adding two cusomized `Button`s and `ImageView` to a scene.
2. Or take a look at "Display Shelf" sample with similar functionality (copy-paste link to browser, cause StackOverflow doesn't understand spaces in links): `http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.1/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Graphics/Display Shelf`
3. Or take a look at dev build of JavaFX 2.2 which has new `Pagination` control which do exactly what you need and even going to support gestures to change pages: [2.2 dev preview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the pagination control looks great, but i don't think i will move to JavaFX 2.2 right now.  I would like to have help on how to refresh my pane to show new picture's item, each time a new item is added or removed from my list of item.

Comment: use `ObservableList` for your pictures and add listener to it, which will update a pane.

Comment: The layout panes have ObservableLists as their children, for example VBox for a vertical layout, HBox for a horizontal layout, TilePane for a tiled layout.  Use something like vbox.getChildren() and modify the resultant ObservableList directly to swap in and out the ImageView's you want.